# NUnit 3.7.1: Assert.Inconclusive with InnerException

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a `OneTimeSetup` where I want to verify integration connections prior to running tests (databases, REST endpoints, etc.), short-circuiting the suite if there is an issue. Consider something like

```
Try
    Dim testContext As DBContext = New DBContext(_configuredConnectionString)

    VerifySQLConnection(testContext)
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim actionableError As String = String.Format(_VERIFY_SQL_CONNECTION_TEMPLATE, _configuredConnectionString)
    Dim actionableException As New ConfigurationException(actionableError, ex)
    'Throw actionableException

    Assert.Inconclusive(actionableError)
End Try
```

If a connection fails, I don't want to fail the test, I want to assert that the entire suite is inconclusive, because the actual test never ran.

I'm noticing that `Assert.Inconclusive` lacks an overload taking in an inner exception. This forces me to either fail all tests, with a full inner exception to inspect, or mark tests as inconclusive, but lose actionable information from an NUnit test runner window.

- Is there a reason for this or is this overload missing an oversight?
- Is there an alternative I could use to get both Inconclusive *and* the full inner exception (not just the message, but stack, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NUnit's `Inconclusive` result is intended to mean that the test simply cannot be run because some pre-condition has not been met. The fact that an exception happens to be thrown is part of the internal implementation - it's how we force the test to stop running at that point - but nothing about the nature of the exception is exposed to the user.

`Assert.Inconclusive` is a manual way to provide such an Inconclusive result. It does so absolutely, without making any particular test, in a similar way to how `Assert.Fail` works. If you want to make a test of some kind, it is "assumed" that you will use the `Assume.That` method to produce the result.

In your case, the `VerifySqlConnection` method sounds like something you should be testing in at least one test method, failing if you can't make it. For other tests that depend on a connection having been made, you could use code similar to...

```
Assume.That(() => VerifySqlConnection(testContext), Throws.Nothing);
```

The above is the C# syntax... I leave VB translation to you. :-)